# Convert Wordpress pages to PDF

Tags: plugins, pdf

Just like I customize the CSS print for a page, I want to be able to convert the page to PDF.

Many plugins I tried just display main content of the page or post without design; just plain text.  I want to be able convert the page to PDF as it is.

Is there a way to do this even without a plugin?

Comment: Yes, you can do it but it isn't something as simple as hacking HTML. If you don't use a plugin you'd end up writing one, more or less. And there are a lot of questions about this already. Look to right under "Related".

Comment: @s_ha_dum I browsed some related questions, but not so much info. Someone suggested to use FPDF library to do that but i think this will take so much time as I'm not fluent in PHP

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. CSS print stylesheets and printing to PDF are not **WordPress** specific issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WP-MPDF](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mpdf/) has always worked extremely well for me and has a decent templating system you can override. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Zach for recommending this plug, although I tried it before asking the question but I didn't give so much attention  to the amazing template system. But now and with customization it did what I want. Thanks

Comment: Great to hear! Have fun :)

Comment: Unfortunately the plugin is deprecated now, afaiu :(

Answer (score -4):

My recommendation would be to try [this free toolkit](http://kitpdf.com/) and convert a Wordpress pages into a pdf file, it worked very well for me.

It has a friendly interface and it's easy to use.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was asked because there was WP integration needed and not a random webservice. Btw, I tried the service and it returns 404s on _every_ link I fed it with when I tried to view the PDF. Please mind the scope of the site for later answers. Thanks.